# Is there a way to keep only defined charaters in a string from a whitelist?

Tags: r, regex, whitelist

I'm looking for a way to use a whitelist that contains digits and the Plus sign "+" to replace all other chars from a string.

```
string <- "opiqr8929348t89hr289r01++r42+3525"
```

I tried first to use:

```
gsub("[[:punct:][:alpha:]]", "", string)
```

but this excludes also the "+":

```
# [1] "89293488928901423525"
```

How can I exclude the `"+"` from `[:alpha:]` ?

So my intension is to use a whitelist instead:

```
whitelist <- c("0123456879+")
```

Is there a way to use `gsub()` in the other way around? Because when I use my whitelist it will identify the chars that should remain.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Yes you are right I copied an example that is not representative for all cases. i have other  punctuation like "-", ".","/", ... in the dataset that i want to exclude. therefor the try with [:punct:] but i don't find a way to explude the "+"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
string <- "opiqr8929348t89hr289r01++r42+3525"
gsub("[^0-9+]", "", string)
# [1] "89293488928901++42+3525"
```

This replaces everything that's not a 0-9 or plus with "".

Comment: This is working as expected. Really great. Thank you also for the explanation with the plus. Helps a lot.

Comment: Dont escape `+` inside `[]`. its not a special character in there. This currently would also keep "\\" which is not what op wants. `string <- "opiqr8929348t89hr289\\r01++r42+3525"`

Comment: @AndreElrico Thanks, I edited the answer to reflect that.